# Action does not get the value from Ajax ActionLink htmlAttribute

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, actionlink, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I have an ajax actionlink where I pass a model and *actionattribute* as additional html attribute

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add action", "SomeAction", "SomeController", Model, new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "SomePartial", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { actionattribute = "a", @class = "new" })
```

The *actionattribute* attribute renders in html source code with the correct value.

The *model* is passed nicely to the action but html *actionattribute* parameter comes empty instead of displaying the value **a**.

Any ideas why? What am I missing? How to get the parameter working?

EDIT ***

Model does not pass the values either. Sorry for confusion.
The model values set up initially in Index action are passed to SomeAction. Otherwise any update to these values in the form are not visible by SomeAction.

This is the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model, string actionattribute)
    {
        ViewBag.Msg = "actionattribute: " + actionattribute;
        ViewBag.Msg += "<br />Counter: " + model.Counter;
        ViewBag.Msg += "<br />Code: " + model.Code;
        ViewBag.Msg += "<br />Type: " + model.Type;

        return this.PartialView("_SomePartialView", model);
    }
```

EDIT 2 ***

1. I can't use Ajax.BeginForm instead of Ajax.ActionLink because I already have Html.BeginForm for the page and can't nested ajax forms inside it.
2. The _SomePartialView is a partial view, the model it uses is a property of a 'main' model and is passed to this partial view _SomePartialView via

   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Main/_SomePartialView.cshtml", Model.SomeProperty)

Comment: Could you provide us with the controller endpoint this link is touching?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that htmlattributes don't map directly to your action parameters. So you could possibly do something like this instead:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add action", "SomeAction", "SomeController", new { model = Model, actionattribute = "a" }, new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "SomePartial", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class = "new" })
```

Hope this solves the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: that passes the parameter but not the model, the model comes null

Answer (score 0):

based on your update you would need to form your action link like this.. updating the routevalues

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add action", "SomeAction", "SomeController", 
    new { Counter = Model.Counter, Code = Model.Code, Type = Model.Type, actionattribute  = "a"}, 
    new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "SomePartial", HttpMethod = "POST" }, 
    new { @class = "new" })
```

Comment: the actionattribute & the model come through but all the model propertys comes null/ not pass through